# 'umfpack.h' not found, but it's in /opt/local/include/

Tags: macos, umfpack

I'm trying to compile a program called hiQlab on OSX 10.8

```
g++ -g -O2 -I`echo /Users/.../Documents/hiQlab/hiqlab-2006-07-20/tools/`/lua/include -I`echo /Users/.../Documents/hiQlab/hiqlab-2006-07-20/tools/`/tolua++/include -c cscmatrix.cc
cscmatrix.cc:13:12: fatal error: 'umfpack.h' file not found

#include "umfpack.h"
```

but I just installed SuiteSparse through macports which includes umfpack and `umfpack.h` is in fact present in default directory `/opt/local/include/`

Do I need to add the path or something?

---

ok after some more searching I found the answer
-- I didn't add the macports paths to my search paths

how dumb =p and since I can't answer my own question for 8 hours, I'll just edit here

```
vi ~/.profile

export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
export MANPATH=/opt/local/share/man:$MANPATH
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/local/include
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/local/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib
alias gcc="gcc -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib"
alias g++="g++ -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib"
```